# Drop down box in django getting populated from a database table column

Tags: django

I searched the same thing on net and got many answers but some how dint get working with any of them.

Table:

1. Report: reportType(foreign key from ReportCategory), name, description
2. Report Category: name, description

forms.py

```
class ReportForm_insert(forms.ModelForm):    
        class Meta:    
        model=Report  
        invent = ReportCategory.objects.all()  
        print invent  
        reportType_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = invent)   
        fields =('name','description',)
```

model.py

```
class ReportCategory(models.Model):  
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    description =  models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Report(models.Model):   
    reportType = models.ForeignKey(ReportCategory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, inside the meta class I am trying to do two things:

Firstly, populating the Report Type dropdown box with the value from
the 'name' column of ReportCategory table.
Secondly, when all the other fields in the form are filled by the user
and the button is pressed, the data in the fields should be saved in
the Report table keeping in mind the foreign key constraint it has
from the ReportCategory table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **forms.py**

```
class ReportForm_insert(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model=Report
```

That is it. Django automatically understands that a drop down has to be created when we declare it as a Foreign key in the model.

Answer (score 2):

```
reportType = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Should be:

```
reportType = models.ForeignKey(ReportCategory)
```

Then on the ReportCategory model add:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Then on your form you don't need any of other stuff

Comment: I dont think so this would display the answer in the form of a drop down box and only text box. Also the drop down box has to be populated from the 'name' column of the ReportCategory table

Comment: ForeignKeys on model forms are (by default) displayed as a <select> element who's options are populated from the queryset provided (by default this is all()).  Also from the docs: The __unicode__ method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field's choices; to provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object, and should return a string suitable for representing it

Comment: If this isn't what you are asking for you might have your schema/description wrong.  I'm reading it as users will be creating Report objects with a form and will need to select the report type from a list of available options.  Those options will be provided by the ReportCategory table and will have a visual representation to the user represented by the name field.

Answer (score 0):

Use InlineFormsets.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

>>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
>>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
>>> author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
>>> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  His model does not use a FK (it should) as well isn't what he's asking for.

Comment: I am using a foreign key Report : reportType(foreign key from ReportCategory)..and I want the column to be shown as a form of a drop down box. I am not quite sure whether this will give me out put in form of drop down box